# Predict a user input using current datetime and past history

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

## The project

I'm working on a small project where users can create events (such as `Eat`, `Sleep`, `Watch a movie`, etc.) and record log entries matching these events.

My data model looks like this (the application itself is in Python 3 / Django, but I don't think it matters here):

```
# a sample event
event = {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Eat',
}

# a sample entry
entry = {
    'event_id': event['id'],
    'user_id': 12,

    # record date of the entry
    'date': '2017-03-16T12:56:32.095465+00:00',

    # user-given tags for the entry
    'tags': ['home', 'delivery'],

    # A user notation for the entry, it can be positive or negative
    'score': 2,

    'comment': 'That was a tasty meal',

}
```

Users can record an arbitrary number of entries for an arbitrary number of events, they can create new events when they need to. The data is stored in a relational database.

Now, I'd like to make data entry easier for users, by suggesting them relevant events when they visit the "Add an entry" form. At the moment, they can select the event corresponding to their entry in a dropdown, but I want to suggest them a few relevant events on top of that.

I was thinking that, given a user history (all the recorded entries), it should be possible to predict likely inputs, by identifying patterns in entries, e.g:

- `Eat` usually happens every day, around noon and 7:00PM
- `Sleep` usually occurs after 10:00 PM
- `Watch a movie` usually occurs after on friday nights after 8:00 PM

Ideally, I'd like a function, that, given a user ID and a datetime, and using the user history, will return a list of events that are more likely to occur:

```
def get_events(user_id, datetime, max=3):
    # implementation

    # returns a list of up to max events
    return events
```

So if I take the previous example (with more human dates), I would get the following results:

```
>>> get_events(user_id, 'Friday at 9:00 PM')
['Watch a movie', 'Sleep', 'Eat']

>>> get_events(user_id, 'Friday at 9:00 PM', max=2)
['Watch a movie', 'Sleep']

>>> get_events(user_id, 'Monday at 9:00 PM')
['Sleep', 'Eat', 'Watch a movie']

>>> get_events(user_id, 'Monday at noon')
['eat']
```

Of course, in the real life, I'll pass real datetimes, and I'd like to get an event ID so I can get corresponding data from the database.

## My question

(Sorry, if it took some time to explain the whole thing)

My actual question is, what are the actual algorithms / tools / libraries required to achieve this? Is it even possible to do?

My current guess is that I'll need to use some fancy machine learning stuff, using something like scikit-learn and classifiers, feeding it with the user history to train it, then ask the whole thing to do its magic.

I'm not familiar at all with machine learning and I fear I don't have enough mathematical/scientific background to get started on my own. Can you provide me some reference material to help me understand how to solve this, the algorithms / vocabulary I have to dig in, or some pseudocode ?

Comment: This could be done with machine learning I think, but it might be overkill for this particular case. It appears you have fairly static buckets (e.g. bucket 7pm-9pm includes sleep,eat,movie). So you could just maintain those buckets with an order of how many entries you have there (e.g. track user 1 submitting eat 50 times in bucket 19:00 so order by the count for this user). This is essentially what your predictive AI would be doing (I believe) unless you train it user-independent, which would then predict common keywords across all users.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear: the tracking is indeed user independant, and user can submit 10s or 100s of different events. Using hand-made counts, I'll probably also loose all the patterns (weekly, monthly, only certain days of the week, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a [k-nearest neighbours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (kNN) approach would be a good starting point. The idea in this specific case is to look for the *k* events that happen closest to the given time-of-day and count the ones that occur the most often.

> #### Example
>
> Say you have as input `Friday at 9:00 PM`. Take the distance of all
>   events in the database to this date and rank them in ascending order.
>   For example if we take the distance in minutes for all elements in the
>   database, an example ranking could be as follows.
>
> ```
> ('Eat', 34)
> ('Sleep', 54)
> ('Eat', 76)
>    ...
> ('Watch a movie', 93)
> ```
>
> Next you take the first *k = 3* of those and compute how often they
>   occur,
>
> ```
> ('Eat', 2)
> ('Sleep', 1)
> ```
>
> so that the function returns `['Eat', 'Sleep']` (in that order).

Choosing a good *k* is important. Too small values will allow accidental outliers (doing something once on a specific moment) to have a large influence on the result. Choosing *k* too large will allow for unrelated events to be included in the count. One way to alleviate this is by using distance weighted kNN (see below).

#### Choosing a distance function

As mentioned in the comments, using a simple distance between two timestamps might lose you some information such as day-of-week. We can solve this by making the distance function `d(e1, e2)` slightly more complex. In this case, we can choose it to be a tradeoff between time-of-day and day-of-week, e.g.

```
d(e1, e2) = a * |timeOfDay(e1) - timeOfDay(e2)| * (1/1440) + 
            b * |dayOfWeek(e1) - dayOfWeek(e2)| * (1/7)
```

where we normalised both differences by the maximum difference possible between times in a day (in minutes) and days of the week. `a` and `b` are parameters that can be used to give more weight to one of these differences. For example if we choose `a = 3` and `b = 1` we say that occurring at the same day is three times more important than occurring at the same time.

#### Distance weighted kNN

You can increase complexity (and hopefully performance) by not simply selecting the *k* closest elements but by assigning a weight (such as the distance) to all events according to their distance of the given point. Let `e` be the input example and `o` be an example from the database. Then we compute `o`'s weight with respect to `e` as

```
          1
w_o = ---------
      d(e, o)^2
```

We see that points lose weight faster than their distance to `e` increases. In your case, a number of elements is then to be selected from the final ranking. This can be done by summing the weights for identical events to compute a final ranking of event types.

#### Implementation

The nice thing about kNN is that it is very easy to implement. You'll roughly need the following components.

- An implementation of the distance function `d(e1, e2)`.
- A function that ranks all elements in the database according to this function and a given input example.

  ```
  def rank(e, db, d):
      """ Rank the examples in db with respect to e using
          distance function d.
      """
      return sorted([(o, d(e, o)) for o in db],
                    key=lambda x: x[1])
  ```
- A function that selects some elements from this ranking.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! My impression is that it would work for finding closest events (by time distance), but it would not be able to identify and use more complex patterns, for example events occuring only on certain week days (but I may be wrong). Anyway, it's a good starting point, do you know any reference material for starting with this solution in Python ?

Comment: @EliotBerriot Updated answer with some notes on choosing a distance function and pointers how to get started.

Comment: This is really helpful! I'll wait a bit more to see if different answers are posted, but otherwise I'll pick your answer :)

Comment: @EliotBerriot I suggest that you try to implement it anyway and see if it fits your needs. If not, you've learned a new algorithm that is often used in practice!